# How can I generate paging links from the URL when using mod_rewrite changes the URL

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, paging

**First of all I am in DESPERATE need of help here PLEASE I will most likely start a bounty as soon as SO lets me.**

I have a pretty large site (social network) MANY PAGES, I am currently doing a complete re-write to build it better then I did 2 years ago.  1 thing I have decided to change is the URLs on my site, there were like this **http://example.com/?p=page-identifier-name**  and sometimes **http://example.com/?p=page-identifier-name&page=2&user=343433** you get the point with ultiple items in the URL, I am now switching to use mod_rewrite, I have actually done it, I have the whole site changed to using it but I have 1 huge problem,

My paging function, I LOVE it, it makes really nice paging like this prev 1 2 - 34 35 36 37 - 189 190 next or similar and work pretty well however now that I have switch to using mod-rewrite, obviously my URLs are different now which breaks my pager, I have tried a few things with no luck yet on making it work correctly again, that is why I have provied the full code to the paging below so if you care to help me you can easily drop it into a page and see how it works yourself.

The paging code currently looks for all keys and values in the URL for `$_GET` it then basicly itterates through all them since some pages have more then others on my site, it then re-build the proper URL with the correct page number and spits it out on the screen for my pager.  So something like **www.example.com/?p=mail.inbox** is now **www.example.com/mail/inbox**, if enough items are on the page though then it will show as **www.example.com/?p=mail.inbox&page=12** now  **www.example.com/?mail/inbox/page/12** another page might have more then just the `p=page` to show and `page=page` number some pages also have user_id's and sort by and just differetn things, now I wouldn't mind having somethings just appended to the pretty url but things like page number I would like to show how I want it to  show, I have all the mod_rewrite and regex working I just need help to make my pager code generate the correct links.  Since all pages are processed through the *index.php* file the page showing is never deeper then the root folder but the it would be nice maybe if I could trick it into thinking it is when it have a pretty url that makes it look like it is in a different folder.  example.com/mail/inbox is really in the root level index and not 2 folders deep,  tried using something like

```
$selfurl = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'/page/'. $pagenumber;
```

If I was on this page **www.example.com/mail/inbox** then this would make a paging link look like this **www.example.com/mail/inbox/page/12** however if I were to click that link, then the new paging links would look like this **www.example.com/mail/inbox/page/12/page/34** so obviously that is not the solution, I am really stuck here and if I can not find a solution then I will have to quit using regex and have some really crappy paging, I would really appreciate anyone who can try to help me, I don't see a soltion but surely there has to be one.

```
<?PHP

class Paging
{

    /*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    * Paging Function
    * //paging(10000, 50, 4); //number of results / items per page / number of page links in center
    * // paging(10000, 50); //or
    */ ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static function show_paging($total_results, $items_per_page, $adjacents = 3)
    {
        //$total_results = $reccnt;
        //$items_per_page = $pagesize;
        // adjacements will determinine how many paging links are in the middle of the outer paging

        if ($total_results > $items_per_page) {
            // build our link URLs
            $url_string = "?";
            foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
                if ($k != "page") { // <-- the key you don't want, ie "page"
                    if ($url_string != "?") {
                        $url_string .= "&"; // Prepend ampersands nicely
                    }
                    $url_string .= $k . "=" . $v;
                }
            }
            $selfurl = $url_string . '&page=';
            $page = $_GET['page'];
            if ($page) {
                $start = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;
            }
            else {
                $start = 0;
            }
            if ($page == 0) {
                $page = 1; //if no page var is given, default to 1.
            }
            $prev = $page - 1; //previous page is page - 1
            $next = $page + 1; //next page is page + 1
            $lastpage = ceil($total_results / $items_per_page); //lastpage is = total_results/ items per page, rounded up.
            $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1; //last page minus 1
            /*
            * Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
            * We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
            */
            $pagination = "";
            if ($lastpage > 1) {
                $pagination .= '<div class="pagingspace"><div class="pager">';
                //previous button
                if ($page > 1) {
                    $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $prev .
                        '" title="go to previous page"><span class="page-numbers prev">prev</span></a>';
                }
                //pages
                if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) { //not enough pages to bother breaking it up{
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                        if ($counter == $page) {
                            $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers current">' . $counter . '</span>';
                        }
                        else {
                            $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $counter . '" title="go to page ' . $counter .
                                '"><span class="page-numbers">' . $counter . '</span></a>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) { //enough pages to hide some{
                        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                        if ($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {
                            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++) {
                                if ($counter == $page) {
                                    $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers current">' . $counter . '</span>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $counter . '" title="go to page ' . $counter .
                                        '"><span class="page-numbers">' . $counter . '</span></a>';
                                }
                            }
                            $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>';
                            $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $lpm1 . '" title="go to page ' . $lpm1 .
                                '"><span class="page-numbers">' . $lpm1 . '</span></a>';
                            $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $lastpage . '" title="go to page ' . $lastpage .
                                '"><span class="page-numbers">' . $lastpage . '</span></a>';
                            //in middle; hide some front and some back
                        }
                        else {
                            if ($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2)) {
                                $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl .
                                    '1" title="go to page 1"><span class="page-numbers">1</span></a>';
                                $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl .
                                    '2" title="go to page 2"><span class="page-numbers">2</span></a>';
                                $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>';
                                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++) {
                                    if ($counter == $page) {
                                        $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers current">' . $counter . '</span>';
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $counter . '" title="go to page ' . $counter .
                                            '"><span class="page-numbers">' . $counter . '</span></a>';
                                    }
                                }
                                $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>';
                                $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $lpm1 . '" title="go to page ' . $lpm1 .
                                    '"><span class="page-numbers">' . $lpm1 . '</span></a>';
                                $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $lastpage . '" title="go to page ' . $lastpage .
                                    '"><span class="page-numbers">' . $lastpage . '</span></a>';
                                //close to end; only hide early pages
                            }
                            else {
                                $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl .
                                    '1" title="go to page 1"><span class="page-numbers">1</span></a>';
                                $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl .
                                    '2" title="go to page 2"><span class="page-numbers">2</span></a>';
                                $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>';
                                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                                    if ($counter == $page) {
                                        $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers current">' . $counter . '</span>';
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $counter . '" title="go to page ' . $counter .
                                            '"><span class="page-numbers">' . $counter . '</span></a>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //next button
                if ($page < $counter - 1) {
                    $pagination .= '<a href="' . $selfurl . $next .
                        '" title="go to next page"><span class="page-numbers prev">next</span></a>';
                }
                else {
                    $pagination .= '<span class="page-numbers prev">next</span>';
                    $pagination .= '</div></div>';
                }
            }
            echo '<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="paginator">';
            echo '<tr><td align="center" height="20" class="black11bold">';
            echo $pagination;
            echo '</td></tr></table>';
        }
    }

    // converts page number to a start position number for MySQL query
    public static function page2db($page, $items_per_page)
    {
        if ($page) {
            $start = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;
        }
        else {
            $start = 0;
        }
        return $start;
    }

}

?>
```

To use

```
<?PHP
//to use the paging functions i do something like this
$pagesize = 10;
$start = Paging::page2db($_GET['page'], $pagesize); //page number and items perpage

//the show the pager links
Paging::show_paging($total_count, $pagesize, 4);

?>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I need to figure out a way to get the value from URLs like this and only have the part minus the domain name, so
**http://example.com/mail/inbox** would only return **/mail/inbox** this should work on and number of directories and should not return valus like `?var1=something` that are on it, so it should only return the folders that are added onto 
a domain the catch is these folders are not real folders, they are created with mod_rewrite in the URL

http://example.com**/mail/inbox**
http://example.com**/forums/category**
http://example.com**/users/online**
http://example.com**/users/online/friends**

I am trying to fix a PHP paging code that is messed up now that I use mod-rewrite, the links it prints to the screen are incorrect because it rebuilds the URL based on the `$_GET` values, this doesnt work anymore as the names in the URLs do not match the `$_GET` values

SO if a URL is http://example.com**/users/online** or http://example.com**/users/online/page/22** then I need to rebuld it into a variabe as http://example.com**/users/online/ then my paging code can add on it's page part if needed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best method that I have found is to pass into the paging function, the URL of the page I am on using

```
$pagingurl = 'http://localhost/mail/inbox/';
Paging::show_paging($total_count, 3, $pagingurl, 4);
```

This seesm liek the best solution for allowing me to use my mod-rewrite URLs

Comment: Yes this is how i go about it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469067/need-help-with-my-pager-php-function-now-that-i-use-mod-rewrite/1469807#1469807
Answer is in this question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you **don´t** have to change anything, if the regex in the mod-rewrite is good, it will not touch your http://domain.com/?p=page-identifier-name&page=2&user=343433 url, it will only process the urls where *folders* are found (folders as in /bla/bla/etc/). So even without your new paging function, everything should work exactly as before with **both the old and the new urls**.

Apart from that I would always recommend to build your url from scratch, adding the necessary elements as needed so that you always know how the url will / can look and design your mod-rewrite regex accordingly.

So, at the start of the page, get all variables (page, page number, sub-page, etc.) and use these elements to build every url.

**Edit:** Ok, it seems your pagination is very apart from the rest of the url so a dirty solution would be to search the url you already have for the page-[0-9] part and replace the number or add that part if it is not found. I wouldn´t really recommend it, but it seems possible.

Comment: The problem is that theory does not work if it did then I wouldn't be trying to get it to work, I mean sure I can keep my old generated paging links and they will load the page but if I go to a URl **domain.com/mail/inbox/page/2** and click on the paging link for page 3 it then loads **domain.com?p=mail.inbox&page=3** instead of **domain.com/mail/inbox/page/3** Everybody just assumes that it still works without modifying the PHP and it DOES need to be modified otherwise I get that problem

Comment: Thanks for realizing I have a problem someone actually downvoted my and voted to close this as if I dreamed this up.  As you say you would not recommend it, do you have a method you would recommend? I need to get it working but also has to be good performance so If I need to re-write code then thats what needs to be done but I really don't even see where to start since the URL's get changed

Comment: Like I said, I would always build the url from the ground up. If you use a separate pagination class perhaps that would mean adding the elements of the url as input for the function. And yes, downvotes without comments suck :(

Comment: By the way, I guess there's no harm either in searching the url for a page number and replace it with the new one (or add it if not found...), it just doesn't feel right :-)

Comment: thanks for the tips, I updated the bottom part of my post with an idea I have if I can't find a better one, this would be a lot easiar I think if the directories were real instead of fake ones made by mod-rewrite